When data is added dynamically, setExtremes do not work
Demo: https://ctknys.csb.app/
Code: https://codesandbox.io/p/sandbox/ctknys
I have a data added dynamically.
I want to have originally an empty chart where data would be added right on the existing plot with existing min/max values for x-axis.
Strangely it works for first two points (see twopoints.png screenshot),but when the third point is added (see threepoints.png screenshot  ), the min/max values of x-axis are updated, no matter what. I tried all possible approaches but nothing helped.
Corresponding parts of vue component:
<template>
  <div class="chart-container">
    <chart
      ref="chartRef"
      :constructorType="'stockChart'"
      :options="chartOptions"
    ></chart>
  </div>
</template>

<script setup>
import { reactive, ref, onMounted, watch } from "vue";
import { Chart } from "highcharts-vue"; // Import Chart component
import Highcharts from "highcharts"; // Import Highcharts core
import Stock from "highcharts/modules/stock"; // Import Stock module
import HighchartsNoData from "highcharts/modules/no-data-to-display"; // Import No Data module

// Initialize Highcharts modules
Stock(Highcharts);
HighchartsNoData(Highcharts);

const initialMin = ref(null);
const initialMax = ref(null);

// Local `priceHistory` array
const priceHistory = ref([]);

// Generate a random number between 0 and 100
const getRandomNumber = () => Math.floor(Math.random() * 101);

// Initialize `priceHistory` with the current time and random value
const initializeHistory = () => {
  const now = Date.now();
  return [{ x: now, y: getRandomNumber() }];
};

// Reference to the chart component
const chartRef = ref(null);

// Reactive chart options
const chartOptions = reactive({
  time: { useUTC: false, timezoneOffset: 60 },
  chart: {
    height: "300px",
    
  },
   
  xAxis: {
    // minRange: 3600000,
    type: "datetime",

    min: initialMin.value,
    max: initialMax.value,
     
  },
  yAxis: {
   
  },
  navigator: {
    enabled: false,
  },
  credits: {
    enabled: false,
  },
  rangeSelector: {
    enabled: false,
  },
  series: [
    {
      name: "Price",
      data: priceHistory.value,
      marker: {
        enabled: true,
        radius: 6,
        fillColor: "#FF5733",
      },
      lineColor: "#FF5733",
    },
  ],
 
 
});

// Function to add a new random point every second
const startUpdatingHistory = () => {
  setInterval(() => {
    const newPoint = { x: Date.now(), y: getRandomNumber() };
    priceHistory.value.push(newPoint);

    // Limit history size to avoid memory issues
    if (priceHistory.value.length > 100) {
      priceHistory.value.shift();
    }

    // Update chart data reactively
    if (chartOptions.series[0]) {
      chartOptions.series[0].data = [...priceHistory.value];
    }
  }, 2000);
};

watch(priceHistory, (newHistory) => {
  if (chartRef.value?.chart) {
    chartRef.value.chart.update({
      xAxis: {
        max: initialMax.value,
      },
    });
    chartRef.value.chart.xAxis[0].setExtremes(
      initialMin.value,
      initialMax.value
    );
    // chartRef.value.chart.xAxis[0].minRange = 3600000;
  }
});

// Initialize the component
onMounted(() => {
  initialMin.value = Date.now();
  initialMax.value = initialMin.value + 2 * 60 * 1000; //
  console.debug("INITIAL???", initialMin, initialMax);
  priceHistory.value = initializeHistory();
  startUpdatingHistory();
});
</script>



your codesandbox links are set to private and not accessible.  make sure you can open them in an incognito mode of your browser before trying to share.  also all relevant code should still be included with the question, exactly for this reason of bad or dead links.

Just changed the access to public. Will update the post with the code in an hour

@yoduh just updated the post with the code

Not sure how you'd like it to work but it seems that either series.addPoint and xAxis.setExtremes work just fine. Here's a demo showing how to dynamically add points and update the xAxis extremes: https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/5jomLvhp/
